# AngularJs: Datepicker-popup is undefined

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm trying to get an angular datepicker working like in the example seen in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/4ht8y4nw/

However when I do I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined'

I know this is caused by the line `datepicker-popup=""` in,

```
          <input
            type="text"
            id="popup"
            class="form-control"
            datepicker-popup=""
            ng-model="today"
            is-open="opened"
            min-date="minDate"
            ng-click="open()"/>
```

But I don't know how to get rid of this error and I can't see the difference between what I am doing and the example.

I have the following scripts included - 
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js,
bootstrap.min.css V3.3.4,
angular.min.js V1.3.15

Comment: _I can't see the difference between what I am doing and the example_ for us to see the same we need your code posted

Comment: As @KirillSlatin said, post all of your code that is relevant to the datepicker.

Comment: Honestly, this is the only relevant code. I don't need anything in my controller until I can run this bit of HTML without getting the error I mentioned. The popup just isn't working. Was curious if anybody else had had this same issue.

Comment: If I copy the bootstrap ui example exactly I get the same issue. Interestingly everything else about it works fine. Even the inline datepicker will work. It's just the popup.

Comment: There IS relevant code. An `input` element with alien attributes will not work in any browser. There is application bootstrapping, there is module creation and proper injection. This is all relevant. Don't you think that angular magically doesn't work on your specific computer? You're definitely doing something wrong. You can try to reproduce that in fiddle. It can give a clue for you. Or if you manage to reproduce SO community will quickly figure out where's the culprit

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alien attributes? All the attributes I'm using I pasted and I know it's the datepicker-popup attribute not being recognised. I should have mentioned that module injection is not the issue as I'm using the bootstrap.ui throughout the rest of my project fine. And of course I know I'm doing something wrong, that's why I posted... Unfortunately my project is very large so i can't just paste in everything I have into fiddle.

Comment: I more just wanted to know if this was a problem other people have had, but there must just be some very small issue in one part of my code causing this that I'll just have to try and hunt down.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need is a format for the datepicker.

```
<input type="text" datepicker-popup="{{format}}">
```

Provide a format in the controller as:

```
$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

What else i see in the fiddle is no method on the popup to start propagation.

```
$scope.open = function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
};
```

The label what you have in the fiddle needs a click event to start propagation.

```
<label for="popup" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></label>
```

See the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ht8y4nw/100/

Comment: I tried this, but I get the same error. I also tried getting rid of the ="" at the end and that also did not make a difference.

Comment: Actually the funny thing is that original fiddle was showing date from start and popup showed from click on input not only the calendar icon to the right. So your changes make UX worse I would say :)

Comment: Agreed. That can be improved. I gave a correct answer to the error of the problem. UX/UI is upto the person who asked this question. :D